# Php Cookie Ignored

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, drupal

I have a module that should be using php to create a cookie if it doesn't already exist. If it doesn't confirm the cookie's existence it creates it and implements a js file, which then shows an overlay. Otherwise the function should just end. The problem, js  loads on every refresh even though it shouldn't. Please help, I highly appreciate it, thank you.

Cookie PHP

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Checks for cookie, non-existent: creates cookies + implements js, else
 * removes specfic content
 */

/*
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function cookie_check_preprocess_page($hook, &$variables) {
        // Check for cookie
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])) {
            // Set variables for setcookie
            $name = 'firsttime';
            $value = 'no';
            // six months
            $expire = time()+(15768000);
            // Directory
            $path = '/~wolfden/';  
            $domain = 'hitechwolf.com';
            // Create cookie
            setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, true, true);
            // Implement the js
            // Welcome Overlay/Button Functionality ONLY ON FIRST TIME VISIT               
            $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'cookie_check');
            drupal_add_js($path . '/js/welcome_button.js');
        }
        else {
            return '';      
        }
}
```

Overlay JS

```
/**
 * @file
 *  Appends Welcome Overlay to page, upon button
 *  click closes overlay
 */

(function ($, Drupal){
    Drupal.behaviors.welcomeOverlay = {
      attach : function() {
          $('#block-panels-mini-welcome-overlay').appendTo('body');
                function clickButton() {
                $('.welcome-content').fadeTo('500', 0, 'linear', function(){
                    $('.welcome-overlay').slideToggle('700', 'linear', function(){
                  $('#block-panels-mini-welcome-overlay').remove();     
                    });     
                });
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
               $('.welcome-overlay').slideToggle('700', 'linear', function(){
                 $('.welcome-content').fadeTo('500', 1, 'linear');  
               });
    }, 1500); 
    $('.w-button').on('click', clickButton);     
  }
 }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

[Site In Question](http://hitechwolf.com/wolfden)

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie is not setting due to one reason. You wrote code to set cookie is

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, true, true);
```

Last 2 parameters you set TRUE. Second last TRUE is for security, it indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client. When set to TRUE, the cookie will only be set if a secure connection exists.

Your site "http://hitechwolf.com/wolfden/" is not https. So your cookie is not setting.

Try it by setting FALSE

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, false, true);
```

Comment: tried it, still the same error,the cookie still doesn't seem to get set, thanks for trying :)

Comment: Set $path = "/" and $domain = ".hitechwolf.com"

Comment: progress, the cookie now exists, according to devtools, but the js still fires anyhow on every page reload...